# What day do they play soccer? OR When do they play soccer?

Tags: american-english

If I want to ask what day of the week they play soccer, should I ask "**What day** do they play soccer?" or "**When do** they play soccer?".

Another example:
"**What day** do you study English at school?" or "**When** do you study English at school?"

Comment: If you think there is a possibility that they will answer “At 3:00pm” and you are specifically looking for a day-of-the-week answer then frame your question to elicit the response you want. Or, ask the easy question and be prepared to follow with another question if you don’t get the answer you’re looking for.

Answer (score 1):

"When" asks for a date, or a day, or a time, or a period of time.

> When do they play soccer?
>
> > They play soccer at 4pm.  /They play soccer in the winter. /They play soccer on Tuesday

You would guess which answer was appropriate from the context (Just like in your language. Nearly every language has an ambiguous word like "When".

What day usually asks for a day of the week.

> What day do they play soccer.
>
> > They play soccer on Tuesday.

"Which day" is often better, since you are selecting from "Monday-Sunday".